# Preventing soft keyboard dismissal after input on mobile sites

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile

The mobile soft keyboard is dismissed after the user presses send on my mobile site. This is not very usable when the user wants to type multiple lines, for example. How do I disable this behavior on my html? Thanks.

Comment: Show your code. What do you mean with "press send"? The "send" on the soft keyboard, or a "send" button in your HTML? What do you mean with "multiple lines"? A `textarea` or multiple text `inputs`?

Comment: @RoToRa: By send I mean the send on the keyboard and the Html element is an `input` tag, not `textarea`. Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: So it's a single input field? How is the user supposed to write multiple lines then?

Comment: @RoToRa: Well my scenario is similar to this comment box. I type a comment, so it gets added to the DOM. Then, if I want to add my next comment, I have to once again click on the input tag to bring up the soft keyboard. I do not want the keyboard to be dismissed till The user focuses out of the input box manually.

Comment: You could try the [`autofocus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-autofocus) property or the `.focus()` method of the input however I believe iOS Safari doesn't support them...